# Duplicate posts in BlogEngine.NET when using Windows Live Writer

Tags: windows-live-writer

I'm always getting duplicate posts when I publish a new post from Windows Live Writer to my instance of BlogEngine.NET. What can be the reason for this? Is it a bug or something wrong with my configuration perhaps? Any help diagnosing this would be appreciated.

I'm using Windows Live Writer 14.0.8064.206 and BlogEngine.NET 1.5 final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encounter this, but after a little bit the double posts appear to go away by themselves.  I think its something to do with BE.NET.

Comment: Yes, i've also noticed this. At first I deleted one of the posts manually but finally I stopped doing that and tried to find out what was going on. Then after I while, as you said, one of the posts was gone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recycle the application pool of your website. There are no duplicate posts, as you can see by the same GUID. The records are just cached.

Comment: I am no longer using BlogEngine.NET so I currently have no way of reproducing the behavior and test your suggestion. However, your explanation seems reasonable.